# Changing Values of one cell based on the Other in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel and VBA. I am making a Project list wherein I have two columns for Status, `Status` and `Status in Words`. In the former I Need to enter the Status in form of numbers, e.g. 50% or 80% and in the latter I Need to enter the Project Status in words i.e. Open, Closed, In Progress etc. My Problem is that when I write 50 % in the first column, the Status in the other column should automatically Change to `In Progress` and vice versa if I type `Closed` in the second column, then the Status in the first column should Change to `100%`. Could anyone tell me how to procede with this in Excel vba.

Comment: You can't do "vice-versa" cell changes using only 2 cells, without VBA. If you manually type in a value in a cell, it will override whatever formula used to be in there to check on the other cell. Your non-VBA option is to use 4 columns - 2 of them are 'input', and 2 of them are 'output'. That way you can enter data in the first 2, and the second 2 will pick up the right value.

Comment: I would gladly use VBA . Could you please guide me how can I proceed with VBA ? @Grade'Eh'Bacon

Comment: Don't use VBA unless you can read the code you are running. If you can read VBA code, please attempt this yourself first, because this website is for specific Q&A, and it is not a code writing service. If you have a question about making your code work, we would be happy to help. As it is, that is too broad of a question to answer.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I completely agree! Please only use this if you understand what you are doing. I write code, but I do a LOT of debugging.

Comment: you don't need vba for this! A formula will suffice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might work. Change 1 to your lower column number and 2 to your larger column number. I couldn't figure out how to tell Excel to check if it was equal to "100%" or "50%", so I had to use 1 and .5  . If anyone knows, feel free to edit or please comment!

```
'This is a global variable, prevents endless loops in worksheet change.
Dim running As Boolean

'When any change is made on the worksheet, sends target as the changed cell
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Checks to see if a worksheet change is already running, if it is, then it quits 
    If running = True Then Exit Sub
    'We are running code now, so prevent endless loops
    running = True
    Dim YourFirstColumn, YourOtherColumn As Integer

    'Set to your values
    YourFirstColumn = 1
    YourOtherColumn = 2

    'If this is a column you want to change
    If Target.Column = YourFirstColumn Then

        'Change values
        If Target.Value = "In Progress" Then
            Target.Offset(0, Abs(YourFirstColumn - YourOtherColumn)).Value = "50%"
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Closed" Then
            Target.Offset(0, Abs(YourFirstColumn - YourOtherColumn)).Value = "100%"
        End If

    'If this is the other column you want to change
    ElseIf Target.Column = YourOtherColumn Then

        'Change values
        If Target.Value = 0.5 Then
            Target.Offset(0, -Abs(YourFirstColumn - YourOtherColumn)).Value = "In Progress"
        ElseIf Target.Value = 1 Then
            Target.Offset(0, -Abs(YourFirstColumn - YourOtherColumn)).Value = "Closed"
        End If
    End If
    running = false
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the code, I guess this was what I was looking for. One question I have, shall I put this as a new module and then try to modify and run it ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no. This should go into the worksheet's code, as it is specific to the worksheet, but otherwise, yes. I would, however, put a breakpoint in at the first line, and walk through it line by line with "F8"  just to be sure that it doesn't mess anything else up in your worksheet. You may even want to save before running it.

Comment: The one drawback with having the vba-code change values in a cell is that you Will not be able to do undo anymore.

Comment: @seadoggie01 the code seems to work perfectly . But Excel crashes after implementing the code. Any idea ? `"method 'range of object' _Worksheet failed"` This is the error I get.

Comment: No... Did you try using a breakpoint and walking through the code? (It works perfectly fine for me.) Is it in the worksheet code or in a module?

Comment: It is the worksheet code. I already had some other code in the worksheet But I guess that is not a Problem...regarding the breakpoint method...the program crashes after executing everything. So the breakpoint cant exactly tell where is it crashing @seadoggie01

Comment: @seadoggie01 This is the problem with writing whole scale code for someone with no VBA inclination - in order to provide value you really need to dig deeply into the fundementals of coding, and even then you leave the OP at the mercy of your code. Please in the future don't provide answers like this, to questions like this. You will burn out after hundreds of explanations of the same ideas and it is better to provide quality answers to quality questions - you will learn more in the process, too!

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I see that now. It seems you have experienced it yourself more than a few times. I have only had the experience of people who have VBA inclination on StackOverflow. My apologies, and thank you for the kind, but much needed, reproval. Best to delete the answer now?

Comment: You can delete it if you like, but it seems that the question will likely get closed as too broad anyway. @Nikky I mean you no offense by all of this, just to encourage you to learn how to code with VBA yourself if you need VBA solutions. Otherwise you run a great risk of either running malicious code found online without knowing it, or of scoping yourself out of a job by being unable to fix work done by others. If you have specific questions when you run into coding problems, then this is definitely the right place for those questions.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Offending a Person and saying I mean no offence is being contradictory. If you would have looked at my Profile, you would realize how new I am to Stackoverflow. And being a begineer I would have loved Hearing some motivational comments rather than such demotivating stuffs. There is always a proper way of communicating things. Maybe you are too experienced to talk politly or help the beginners. But one day even the beginners become experienced. :)

Comment: @seadoggie01 Thanks alot for your help. You made me teach alot. I appreciate :)

Comment: @seadoggie01 I figured out the Problem as to why it was crashing. Because the code was in a worksheet so I needed to turn all the other macros off while running this code. So I had to use `Application.EnableEvent = False` before updating any Event and then follow with `Application.EnableEvent = True` . Again Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: @Nikky Please don't take my comments personally; I don't know you and don't mean anything against your character. My comments come from experience of dealing with many, many users on this site who barely know how to open up the VBA window and still want users to give them code to perform their exact tasks. This is not a good way to learn and really does increase separation from one's work. I have had co-workers who operated on a similar basis, and proudly talked about "running macros over the problem to fix it for the office", without knowing more than how to press "play". It is dangerous.

Comment: @Nikky I see that you are interpreting, debugging, and editing the code provided to you here - which is positive. But please keep in mind in the future that stackoverflow is not intended as a code-writing service, and in general the site responds well to specific questions, and poorly to broad requests.